# Parsing functions in perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

i'm generating a list of function calls from another script like this:

```
<<START>>set('element','prop','value');get('element','value');alert('something');run('script','params',return');<<END>>
```

The whole language is functions with some parameteres and that's it.
I want to execute them in sequence, just like they are.

So i do this:

```
my $result;
my $script= 'the script written above';
while ( $script =~ m/(\w)\(\'.+\'\);/i){
      callfunction($1,$2,$result); #the function that handles the calls
}
```

(i think this works, not checked)

But the thing is that i need this to be more robust and i think there has to be an alternative to regex and to be able to check a bad syntax, remove white space, and add comments.

Comment: If you want ***robust***, you'll need to specify a grammar, and write an actual parser. It doesn't have to be complicated, but it needs a specification.

Comment: Why not just take any existing parser and use that? YAML? JSON?

Comment: You could also benefit from looking into [`do FILE`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html).

Comment: how should i use a JSON parser to do this? How would you go about making a parser with perl?

Comment: @alfa64 Look up the documentation at http://search.cpan.org.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go more robust, maybe look at [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) - either [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) or [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) benefits from underlying robust parser and specification.